# Write records into file : c

Tags: c

```
int main()
{

    FILE *fp;
    char another = 'Y';
    struct emp
    {
            char name[20];
            int age;
            float bs;
    };
    struct emp e;

    fp = fopen("employee.dat", "w");

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
            printf("file cannot be opened for writing\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    while(another == 'Y')
    {
            printf("\n enter name, age and basic salary: ");
            scanf("%s %d %f", e.name, &e.age, &e.bs);
            fprintf(fp, "%s %d %f\n", e.name, e.age, e.bs);

            printf(" Add another record (Y/N)");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", &another);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
```

In this program I am trying to write records into file named, employee.dat. Program executed fine, but it will takes only one record of employee and then program gets terminated. It is not asking for next record to add i.e.,

```
 fflush(stdin); 
 scanf("%c", &another);
```

are not getting executed in the program.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you're experiencing is that `scanf("%c", &another);` only grabs a single character from the input buffer. This would be fine, except that there's still a newline left in the input buffer that resulted from hitting 'enter' after your input. You need to clear the input buffer after you use `getchar()` like this:

```
char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n');
```

Comment: No need!! noly use flushall(); after scanf

Comment: @OneManCrew what do you mean "no need"? it's another way to do it, just as good as yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
while(another == 'Y' || another == 'y')
    {
            printf("\n enter name, age and basic salary: ");
            scanf("%s %d %f", e.name, &e.age, &e.bs);
            fprintf(fp, "%s %d %f\n", e.name, e.age, e.bs);

            printf(" Add another record (Y/N)");

            another=getch();
            //scanf("%c", &another);

    }
```

Comment: `flushall` is not a standard function. And in any case, trying to flush an input stream is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can fixed it simply by use : `scanf("\n%c",&another);` instead of `scanf("%c",&another);`

```
scanf("%s %d %f", e.name, &e.age, &e.bs);
```

Example--->Here your input is : name_1 22 6000.000 <"Enter">

Then in the buffer : name_1 -->e.name 22-->e.age 6000.00-->e.bs <"Enter">-->nothing

```
fflush(stdin);//it didn't delete the <"Enter">.
scanf("\n%c", &another);//here we deal with <"Enter">
```